# how to use if and else for checkbox or select in redux

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

i want to use Redux checkbox and select option as if and else in front-end.
in [Redux documents](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/checkbox/) i didn't found any thing about if & else.

i want something like this:

```
<?php if ($redux_demo['opt_checkbox']) { echo "my text" } else { echo"the other text" } endif ?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework, but a checkbox is generally speaking either set (if it was checked) or not set (if it wasn't checked). You can use `isset()` to check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php 
$checkboxset = "ABC";
if ($redux_demo['opt_checkbox']==$checkboxset) { echo "my text" } else { echo"the other text" } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!(isset($redux_demo['opt_checkbox']))) 
{ 
    echo "my text"; 
}
else 
{ 
    echo"the other text" 
}
```